# Pasting a Screen shot into a text area on a web page

Tags: java, windows, apache-flex, flash

Is it possible to take a screen shot (using the Print Screen) and paste it from the System Clipboard directly into a web pages text area field (which I would create)?  Do I need a browser plug-in? Can Flash do this?

**The solution only has to work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Why does it only have to work in Internet Explorer?

Comment: In general, you should always support multiple browsers.  Here, you should at least offer a regular upload other browsers or for people who don't want your ActiveX control.

Comment: @Slaks - Duly Noted...The reason it only has to work in IE is because the environment in which I'm building this for only uses IE. Otherwise it would need to be a cross browser solution.

Comment: I thought so.  What if they change their mind later?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible without a plugin.

It's not possible in Flash or Silverlight either, although it is possible in AIR.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to write a custom ActiveX Control in order to do this. The control should automatically take a screenshot and send captured image to server-side code..
There is one more option - create a java applet, which will do the job, and also will help you to avoid cross browser issue.

Comment: Then you need to create ActiveX control

Comment: Do you know of a website that talks about create the solution that you are talking about?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa229115%28VS.60%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974283.aspx
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dsandor/ActiveXInNet11102005040748AM/ActiveXInNet.aspx